# Error phpmyadmin pma__tracking and others does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I recently downloaded XAMPP on my Mac, running Yosemite. Once installed, I tried to use phpmyadmin. I was able to create a database and in the SQL tab create a Table for the database using the "CREATE TABLE ..." query, but I cannot view that database or any of the databases that came loaded with the program. Anytime I click on the database name on the left hand side, I get an error saying that

"#1932 - Table pma__tracking does not exist in engine"

This error also occurs when I try to run "select * ..." queries from the SQL tab.

I have tried altering the config.inc.php file as suggested in other posts, and this did not work. I tried importing the create_tables.sql from the example folder and it gives the same error.

I am able to write .php scripts to query the database created and to add/retrieve data from it, but I cannot do any of this through the phpmyadmin tool, which would be very helpful, and I think might cause more problems later in my development.

Any thoughts on how to configure/set up phpmyadmin to work as its supposed to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do both: use the .sql script to create these configuration storage tables, and specify their name in config.inc.php. Afterwards, log out and log in to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

As i try to import "create_tables.sql" I get an error thrown from this:

SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'phpmyadmin'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

I edited all of the table names mentioned in create_tables.sql in config.inc.php to the form:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';

Doing this and importing the .sql still gives the same error.
Am I doing something wrong/misunderstading your advice? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you first comment out all references to these tables in config.inc.php before you try to import create_tables.sql.